# add method call to each method in a class

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I have class with many methods:

```
public class A {
    public string method1() {
        return "method1";
    }
    public string method2() {
        return "method2";
    }
    public string method3() {
        return "method3";
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public string methodN() {
        return "methodN";
    }
}
```

I would like to add call to doSomething() in each method, for example:

```
public string methodi() {
    doSomething();
    return "methodi";
}
```

What is the best way to do so? Is there any suitable design pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using AOP is already a good answer, it was my first idea too.

I tried to figure out a good way doing it without AOP though and came up with this idea (using the Decorator pattern):

```
interface I {
  String method1();
  String method2();
  ...
  String methodN();
}

class IDoSomethingDecorator implements I {
  private final I contents;
  private final Runnable commonAction;

  IDoSomethingDecorator(I decoratee, Runnable commonAction){
    this.contents = decoratee;
    this.commonAction = commonAction;
  }

  String methodi() {
    this.commonAction().run();
    return contents.methodi();
  }
}
```

You could then decorate the construction of A (which implements I):

```
I a = new IDoSomethingDecorator(new A(),doSomething);
```

It is basically no rocket science and in fact results in more code than your first idea, but you are able to inject the common action and you separate the additional action from the class A itself. Further, you can turn it off easily or use it only in tests, for instance.

Comment: Nice to pass in the common operation as ctor parameter. Hmm, wondering if someone has used java dynamic proxies (C# transparent proxy) to allow for a generic wrapper class...

Comment: I think, he wanted to do `this.commonAction().run();` in every method *and* avoid repeating the code.

Comment: Good enough! this is what I was after for. just use I instead of A in private final A contents; Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is a typical use case for AOP (aspect oriented programming). You'd define the insertion points for the method calls and the AOP engine adds the correct code to the class file. This is often used when you want to add log statements without cluttering your source files.

For java you could add the [aspectj](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) library

For C# and .NET have look at [this blog](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/). Looks like a good starter.

Comment: It's only appropriate to use AOP if doSomething() is a cross-cutting concern (like you suggest, logging). If it's relevant to the core business of the class, AOP will just confuse matters.

Comment: @artbristol - agree - I had the impression that ths question was about  cross-cutting concerns: a practical way to have all methods call `doSomething()` (like `log.info("Just entered method")`) without having to write the source line into the methods.

Comment: Actually, I do think what @Naor need is a typical usage of proxy pattern, and CGLIB(http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) and Dynamic proxy(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) will do the job. Actually, AOP in Spring framework use them a lot internally.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to move from my asp.net project to aspectj just to save a few lines..

Comment: (the question is tagged c# and java, you didn't tell us, that you have an asp.net project...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not having a single function?

```
public string methodi(int i) {
    doSomething();
    return "method" + i.toString();
}
```

Or you may write a function which takes an Func parameter and call this function instead of your functions.

```
    public string Wrapper(Func<string> action)
    {
        doSomething();
        return action();
    }
```

and call your functions from this function;

```
string temp = Wrapper(method1);
```

Comment: about your "single function" suggest - each method does something else. It was only an example..

Comment: then the second part is just the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection.

```
public String callMethod(int i) {
  doSomething();  
  java.lang.reflect.Method method;    
  try {
    method = this.getClass().getMethod("method" + i);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // ...
  }
  String retVal = null;
  try {
    retVal = method.invoke();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) { }
  return retVal;
}
```